# Allow PHP to execute linux commands

Tags: php, linux

I am dynamically creating files with laravel, I need to give them specific permissions by using chmod and change the user and group with chown.

I tried to enter the following lines to my `/etc/sudoers` by using `visudo`.

***NOTE***: Always use `visudo` otherwise you might [corrupt the file](https://superuser.com/questions/1190409/ubuntu-how-to-fix-empty-sudoers-file?noredirect=1#comment1727470_1190409).

---

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: chmod
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: chown
```

But I get syntax errors on these lines.

Comment: Giving a web server user permission to change file ownership and flags as root is potentially very very dangerous.  An attacker in theory could, for example, make your private keys world-readable or replace your SSL certificate.  I hope you're taking every possible care with this!

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how a hacker could possibly do this. He would need full access to my webserver.

Comment: They could always take advantage of some other vulnerability.  For example if you have a script for handling file uploads then they might find a way to co-opt it to upload a malicious PHP file.  I know that if they manage to do that they can already potentially do some damage but there's no need making it any easier for them.

Answer (score 2):

You always have to use the full path to the binary:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown
```

Comment: Can only accept in 2 days. I answered it by myselve in Q&A style to share the knowledge